# High-Level Cryptography Question - RSA & ECDSA Compatibility?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am developing an application to represent the classic cryptography situation of Alice & Bob.

Basically, Alice is encrypting a msg and sending it over to Bob. Bob will decrypt this msg and get the plaintext.

Currently, RSA is being used. Alice uses Bob's public key to encrypt, sends it over, and Bob should use his own private key to decrypt it.

The issue is that I am using a proprietary cryptography library that is running into issues with Bob's side of the decryption. It just isn't happening. The issue is that the library does not recognize/cannot recognize the RSA private key stored in a DER file to decrypt the msg.

An idea was to try to use ECDSA key for Bob's side instead of the RSA key.

I am new to combining different crypto algos together, so this brings up a lot of questions. I want to be pretty sure it'll work before I begin making these changes...

Logic:

1. RSA and ECDSA are based off 2 different algorithms.
   Therefore, they couldn't be used together. I'd have to change both keys so they are ECDSA.
2. Generate an ECDAS key pair and use that instead of RSA!
3. Issue: ECDSA is a signature algorithm, it does not perform encryption.

Since ECDSA doesn't do encryption. I can't have Alice encrypt w/ RSA and then send it over to Bob and expect the ECDSA signature verification & decryption to work.

What is the simplest way to reconcile my current application so that Bob can use ECDSA?

Source: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99779/how-to-encrypt-with-ecdsa

I don't totally understand the "2 keypair solution" for Alice & Bob each. What does that exactly mean?

Should Alice & Bob *each* have a RSA key pair and ECDSA key pair?

Comment: It seems you've found the website where your question would be on-topic, and even better, it's been answered there! So why not ask for clarification there too?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks you're right. Closing this q.